# Get User Token Slack for setPresence

Tags: node.js, bots, slack

I would like to modify the presence or not of several users with the api slack (https://api.slack.com/methods/users.setPresence) For that I need the token of each user. How can I get it to change the presence of users

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to collect user tokens from all users here is the approach:

- Create a Slack app for your Team
- "Force" every user to install this Slack appp
- Collect and store the user tokens gathered during each installation

You will only have to do this once per new user for your workspace.

Comment: I'm calling this and get back 200 ok but the green light does not turn on for the users.